# How to find out which months in a year range that's having 5 Saturdays between two given dates as per the inputs?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle18c

**Only through Query mode, no execution block  method.**

i have tried the following but no luck

```
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(dt, 'mon'),
    COUNT(*) AS noofsat
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            from_date + 1 AS dt
        FROM
            dual
        CONNECT BY
            level <= (
                SELECT
                    TO_DATE - from_date
                FROM
                    dual
            )
    )
WHERE
    TO_CHAR(dt, 'd') = 7
GROUP BY
    TO_CHAR(dt, 'mon')
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 5
```

i need only the month and year which has five Saturdays like  **August 2019**

Comment: Where are `from_date` and `to_date` coming from; and what kind of values will they have - year start/end, or any dates that happen to be a year apart, or any two dates? (`to_date` will cause you issues anyway, as that's a function name...)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good question, In my situation I needed exactly the same thing but in SQL Server, and this is how I did it, I will post the answer for those that end up here looking for a SQL Server solution.

I ended up building a Date Dimension in my Data Warehouse and querying it:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##Dates


 CREATE TABLE ##Dates(DateValue Date, 
                      YearValue INT, 
                      MonthValue INT, 
                      DayValue INT,
                      WeekDayValue INT)


  DECLARE @start DATE = '2019-01-01'
  WHILE @start < '2019-12-31'
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO  ##Dates(DateValue,
                         YearValue, 
                         MonthValue, 
                         DayValue,
                         WeekDayValue)
    VALUES(@start,
            DATEPART(YY,@start), 
            DATEPART(mm,@start), -- In oracle TO_CHAR(dt, 'mon')
            DATEPART(dd,@start),
            DATEPART(dw,@start)) --In oracle  TO_CHAR(dt, 'd')

    SET @start = DATEADD(dd,1,@start)
  END



  SELECT MonthValue, SUM(CASE WHEN WeekDayValue = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumOfSaturdays FROM ##Dates
WHERE DateValue BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-12-01'
GROUP BY MonthValue
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN WeekDayValue = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 4
```

Output:

```
MonthValue  NumOfSaturdays
3            5
6            5
8            5
11           5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get the start of each month covered by your date range; this uses a pair of made-up fixed values as it isn't clear where you are getting your range from:

```
select add_months(trunc(date '2019-03-15', 'MM'), level - 1) as month_start
from dual
connect by level <= ceil(months_between(date '2019-11-21', date '2019-03-15'));

MONTH_STAR
----------
2019-03-01
2019-04-01
2019-05-01
2019-06-01
2019-07-01
2019-08-01
2019-09-01
2019-10-01
2019-11-01

9 rows selected.
```

You can then manipulate those dates in various ways. You can use the `next_day()` function to find the first Saturday of the month - based on the *previous* day, in case the 1st of the month is itself a Saturday. If you then add 28 days to that, you get the fifth Saturday of that month - or, for months with only four Saturdays, the first Saturday in the following month. So if you compare those generated Saturdays, if they are in the same month then that month must actually have five Saturdays.

```
select month_start,
  next_day(month_start - 1, 'SATURDAY') as first_sat,
  next_day(month_start - 1, 'SATURDAY') + 28 as poss_fifth_sat,
  extract(month from month_start) as month_num,
  extract(month from (next_day(month_start - 1, 'SATURDAY') + 28)) as poss_fifth_sat_month
from (
  select add_months(trunc(date '2019-03-15', 'MM'), level - 1) as month_start
  from dual
  connect by level <= ceil(months_between(date '2019-11-21', date '2019-03-15'))
);

MONTH_STAR FIRST_SAT  POSS_FIFTH  MONTH_NUM POSS_FIFTH_SAT_MONTH
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------------------
2019-03-01 2019-03-02 2019-03-30          3                    3 -- same
2019-04-01 2019-04-06 2019-05-04          4                    5
2019-05-01 2019-05-04 2019-06-01          5                    6
2019-06-01 2019-06-01 2019-06-29          6                    6 -- same
2019-07-01 2019-07-06 2019-08-03          7                    8
2019-08-01 2019-08-03 2019-08-31          8                    8 -- same
2019-09-01 2019-09-07 2019-10-05          9                   10
2019-10-01 2019-10-05 2019-11-02         10                   11
2019-11-01 2019-11-02 2019-11-30         11                   11 -- same

9 rows selected.
```

You don't actually need to see those values, I'm just showing the working. But you can use the last two as a filter instead:

```
select month_start
from (
  select add_months(trunc(date '2019-03-15', 'MM'), level - 1) as month_start
  from dual
  connect by level <= ceil(months_between(date '2019-11-21', date '2019-03-15'))
)
where extract(month from month_start)
  = extract(month from (next_day(month_start - 1, 'SATURDAY') + 28));

MONTH_STAR
----------
2019-03-01
2019-06-01
2019-08-01
2019-11-01
```

You can then format those dates however you wish.

---

One possible issue (I'm sure there are others) is mentioned [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/NEXT_DAY.html):

> The argument *char* must be a day of the week in the date language of your session, either the full name or the abbreviation.

So the code above will work as long as your session date language is English. If you can be 100% sure that everyone running this will always be using the same session settings then you use that fixed value (or whatever language is appropriate).

If you can't control that then you can't override the date language as you can with some other functions. As a workaround you could use a known Saturday date to obtain the current date language's name or abbreviation for Saturday, without you needing to know what the language actually is:

```
alter session set nls_date_language = 'Spanish';

select month_start
from (
  select add_months(trunc(date '2019-03-15', 'MM'), level - 1) as month_start
  from dual
  connect by level <= ceil(months_between(date '2019-11-21', date '2019-03-15'))
)
where extract(month from month_start)
  = extract(month from (next_day(month_start - 1, to_char(date '2000-01-01', 'Dy')) + 28));

MONTH_STAR
----------
2019-03-01
2019-06-01
2019-08-01
2019-11-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your date source to:

```
    SELECT
        TO_DATE('20190101','YYYYMMDD') + (LEVEL - 1) AS dt
    FROM
        dual
    CONNECT BY
        level <= 365
```